# csv-commons - withSkipHeaderRecord option doesn't skip anything

Tags: java, csv, parsing, header, apache-commons-csv

I have usual csv file with header

```
f1, f2, f3
1, 2, 3
```

and I try to parse it:

```
 Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withIgnoreEmptyLines().withSkipHeaderRecord().parse(in);
            records.forEach(record -> {
               ...
```

But anyway the first record is header anyway.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 6):

specify that file have header to skip:

```
CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().withSkipHeaderRecord();
```

Comment: With v1.9.0 it is now slightly different CSVFormat.EXCEL.builder().setHeader().setSkipHeaderRecord(true)

Answer (score 2):

I know, right? Say you had a bowl full of green, brown and red M&Ms. And you decided to skip the blue ones. Do you see where I'm going with this? You don't *have* a header record.

Try .withFirstRecordAsHeader(). I think you'll be pleased.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Ion Freeman wants to say is that you can skip the header if you first state that the first line is the header like so: (not tested).

```
 Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withIgnoreEmptyLines().withFirstRecordAsHeader().withSkipHeaderRecord().parse(in);
```

In my case, that wasn't possible because I had an invalid header with duplicates. I had to remove it via another way. I threw it away by reading the first line.

```
in.readLine();  // in = BufferedReader or an other Reader
records.forEach(record -> {
...
```